# Box sync for ubuntu, as window, Mac OS X?

Tags: sync

Is there any solution to have box sync for ubuntu (like dropbox, ubuntu one...), as window, Mac OS X?
https://www.box.com/settings/sync

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Box.com supports WebDAV, which is a protocol that enables remote sharing, syncing and versioning.
Although I havnt tried it myself, this:

http://xmodulo.com/2013/02/how-to-mount-box-com-cloud-storage-on-linux.html

seems like a decent step by step tutorial.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: matv1: your instruction is the mounting cloud storage on linux, not a sync like dropbox, ubuntu one...., therefore the access of the mounted folder "box.com" having matters with slow speed, not available in offline mode. But for sure it helps.